# `Model.to_a.each` gives me the whole array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table `Status` already seeded. I wanted to get:

```
['Aberto', 'Pendente', 'Concluido', 'Fechado']
```

and when I type:

```
Status.all.to_a.each { |u| u.nome }
```

I get:

```
[#<Status id: 1, nome: "Aberto">, #<Status id: 2, nome: "Pendente">, #<Status id: 3, nome: "Concluido">, #<Status id: 4, nome: "Fechado">]
```

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Comment: You need `Status.all.map &:nome`, Or if you are using rails > 3.1, you can do `Status.pluck(:nome)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [***pluck***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

```
Status.pluck(:nome) # => ['Aberto', 'Pendente', 'Concluido', 'Fechado']
```

Comment: I agree with Pavan's post, using `pluck` means you aren't pulling in a bunch of records before just grabbing a single attribute from each.

Answer (score 7):

`Array#each` is used for iteration, `Array#map` is used to for mapping. Here you wanted to **map** *nome* to each *status*. Therefore, just use `Array#map`:

```
Status.all.to_a.map { |u| u.nome }
```

Or even better, the shortcut:

```
Status.all.to_a.map(&:nome)
```

Comment: `to_a` isn't necessary here.

Comment: @MarekLipka, correct. I'm not saying this is the way `nome` should be extracted here. I definitely would have used `pluck` instead. I am just answering OP's question.

Comment: Ah, the `.to_a` is in the question.

Comment: The OP selected Pavan's answer, which may help but does not answer the question. ndn's answer should have been selected.

Comment: @sawa Can I know why my answer doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Pavan the OP is asking *"can anyone tell me what's happening?"* - your answer provides a solution / workaround without answering that question.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks. I concentrated on the OP's expected result and missed that part :)